# Jupgrade login error

Tags: joomla2.5

I want to upgrade my site which is working on joomla 1.5.26 to joomla 2.5.
I copied the stable package of joomla 2.5.2 in the jupgrade folder of my site and unzipped it.
I installed jupgrade and I get the message saying jupgrade installed successfully. But when I try to login at the backend(mysite/jupgrade/administrator) i get the login screen with the message given below.
Note: When upgrading skip download,skip decompress is set to yes and Delete previous migration,Enable migration debug,Enable Mootools version debug  is set to no.

```
    JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_COMPONENT_NOT_LOADING
    JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_COMPONENT_NOT_LOADING
    Error loading component: com_login, 1
```

Can anybody tel me how to resolve this error?